# IOS how do i make a collapsable menu like this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

[image]

Hi there. Im new to ios, and i've been giving this assignment. I need to make a expandable/collapsable menu that can hold controls.

I have no idea on how to achieve this, and searching the internet has not proven fruitful - except for some navigation dropdown menus like this: 
https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu

which is very nice, but ment for navigation, as i see it..

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

EDITED: Apparently the question was to broad.. I'll try to elaborate.

I need a menu i can place in certain viewcontrollers - each different viewcontroller can have different options, and often many different options. Therefore i need to add a menu that can be collapsed/expanded by a touch on the arrowbutton - as illustrated on pictures, and the collapsable menu must be able to contain different controls, depending on the context of where it is used.

After more research, i'm thinking a the usage of a container might be a part of the solution, and some animation to handle the expand/collapse.

So basicly - the menu could be something like the equivilant of an Android fragment, that can be inserted in the activities needed.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: How long will this be on hold after i edit post?

Comment: Closed just like that?? Really? No hints for a new objective c developer? After my edit i really dont see how this question is too "broad".

Answer (score 1):

You will try to play with Autolayout constraints ,

Ex : The height constraint of the container view is 60 in expanded mode ,if you want to collapse it change it to 0.